# Convert LINQ method syntax with method withing .Select() to LINQ query syntax

Tags: c#, .net, linq, select, lambda

I currently have the following code:

```
dataSource.Where(row => row.Value == 1)
          .Select(row => {row["Text"] = translatedText; return row;})
          .Single();
```

So my goal is to select the DataRow with "Value=1" and at the same time set the value in the "Text"-column to some other value (in my case a string-variable transalatedText).

This already works fine with the method chain mentioned above but I generally prefer the LINQ syntax. Is there a possibility to translate this method chain to LINQ?

My problem is that I do not know how to translate the function in the Select-method to LINQ-format. I dont want to create a new DataRow but want to really edit the selected one. (So I don't want to use `from x in y where z select new DataRow(...)` but to really edit my `x` if possible)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to translate this method chain to LINQ?

(By "to LINQ" I believe you mean "to query expression syntax".)

Not directly, no. Effectively, you can only convert expression-bodied lambda expressions into query syntax. There's a good reason for that: LINQ is designed *not* to have side effects, whereas your "query" *does* have side-effects.

I would personally write your code like this instead:

```
var row = DataSource.Single(row => row.Value == 1);
row["Text"] = translatedText;
```

That neatly separates the querying from the side-effect. If you *really, really* want to use query expression syntax, you *could* write:

```
var query = (from row in DataSource
             where row.Value == 1)
             select HorribleMutatingMethod(row)).Single();
...

private DataRow HorribleMutatingMethod(DataRow row)
{
    row["Text"] = translatedText;
    return row;
}
```

... but please don't.

Comment: Yeah, i mean "query expression syntax", thanks for that.
Your solution works fine for my case, but I wanted to keep the question as "general" as possible (eg. a renaming with _Where(row => new []{1, 2, 3}.Contains(row.Value)_)